# Ergodox and backtick / grave / accent (ErgoDox EZ Oryx with QWERTZ)

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

Keyboard: ErgoDox
Keyboard-Layout: DE (german)
Layout-Configurator: [Oryx](https://configure.zsa.io/ergodox-ez/layouts/MnddY/latest)

How to enter the ` grave (aka backtick / accent) in a way, that you don't need to press it twice to appear?

Answer (score 2):

After a couple of time, I figured out, how it works.

1. Open the Oryx-Configurator
2. Edit the Key where the ` should appear
3. Choose Tab Macro
4. Enter `SHIFT`+`=` (but choose the general = not the "num-block" one!)
   [image: SHIFT+=]
5. Enter a general Whitespace
   [image: WhiteSpace]

Result should look like this:

[image: Overview of Macro Setting]

If your PC has now set QWERTZ (german) Keyboard-Layout as general Layout, the ` works with one single click.

Comment: So random ... but thanks :-D